# Como pegar dados do Lado Cliente para o Servidor

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, geolocalização

Olá.

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em .NET CORE e na pagina de acesso vai pegar a geolocalização do cliente com as coordenadas de Longitude e Latitude. Porém, fiz este código usando javascript, e o mesmo ira rodar no lado do cliente, fiz um implemento para preencher 2 Label com as informações, mas não estou conseguindo enviar estas para o meu servidor, minha ideia e armazenar a localização (Com o conhecimento do cliente), porém não esta funcionado, não estou conseguindo fazer isso.

Abaixo o javascript que estou pegando a localização, e na sequencia como estao as label dentro do meu html, nao coloquei ele todo mas esta dentro de uma form, estou.

### Javascript

```
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("lat");
    var y = document.getElementById("lot");

    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else { 

            y.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.textContent = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude;
        y.innerHTML = "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
        <%--Codigo para pegar as cordenadas e setar as mesmas nas Labels --%>
        $("#lblat").text("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude);
        //$("#lblog").text("Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
        $("#lblog").text("Longitude: " +position.coords.longitude);
        $("#endereco").text("Longitude: " +position.coords.longitude);
    }


    $(document).ready(function carregar() {
        getLocation();
        showPosition();
    });
</script>
```

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
            <hr />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Controle de Acesso "></asp:Label>
             <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblat" runat="server" > </asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblog" runat="server" Text=""> </asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lbIp" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lbHost" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
             <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
             <asp:Label ID="lboutro" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <hr />
            <br />
            <br />
             <asp:Label ID="lat" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
               <br />
             <asp:Label ID="lot" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

abaixo um print da minha aplicação pegando as informações, quero pegar elas para armazenar em um banco de dados e usar isso para comparar os locais de acesso do cliente, e caso tenha algum acesso em um local diferente executara alguma ação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se você deseja enviar dados do client para o servidor você precisa fazer uma requisição GET ou POST para assim. Assim como implementar a recepção desse request no servidor para o tratamento necessário.

Comment: O que não faz muito sentido é você estar utilizando componentes do ASP.NET que com a declaração `Runat="Server"`, sendo que eles não têm nenhum interação com o servidor e sua manipulação está sendo realizada apenas no lado do cliente, via javascript. Isso está servindo apenas para deixar a renderização de sua página um pouco mais lenta e adicionando uma carga desnecessária no lado do servidor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para enviar as informações do cliente ao servidor, aconselho utilizar ajax, já que está trabalhando com o javascript e também não precisa da interação do cliente. O .Net Core não trabalha com a sintaxe de "Runat=Server".

Essa documentação deixa bem claro como efetuar o procedimento:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/